I can't communicate from C++ to GnuRadio with ZeroMQ REQ
I have a C++ code to send commands and change parameters in a GnuRadio flowgraph. To do a simple test I'm trying to send a string from a C++ code and visualize it in GnuRadio.
This is my C++ code:
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // Create a ZeroMQ context and a REQ socket
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, zmq::socket_type::req);
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:55555");  // Ensure this matches GNU Radio's address
   
    std::string msg_content = "Hello World";

    // Create a ZeroMQ message with the content
    zmq::message_t request(msg_content.size());
    memcpy(request.data(), msg_content.c_str(), msg_content.size());

    // Send the message to GNU Radio
    socket.send(request, zmq::send_flags::none);

    // Receive the reply from GNU Radio (required for REQ socket)
    zmq::message_t reply;
    socket.recv(reply);

    return 0;
}

The GnuRadio is only 2 blocks: ZMQ REQ Message Source connected to a Message Debug block like the 2 blocks at the bottom of figure 1 here https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/ZMQ_REP_Message_Sink
In ZMQ REQ Message Source I set tcp://127.0.0.1:55555
I did a TCP dump to make sure my C++ sends something, and I can see the "Hello World" strings.
I also tried to send TCP messages directly from Ubuntu: echo "Hello, World!" | nc 127.0.0.1 55555, and I still see them in the TCP dump, but still nothing in GR.
The only way I see the strings in GnuRadio is if I create another flowgraph with ZMQ REP Message Sink sending to the first flowgraph

This question is similar to: How to send a parameter to a GnuRadio block from C++ using UDP?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

as I said i the answer to that question, you need to put serialized PMT in these messages, not just some string.

Additionally, if your C++ is creating a REQ socket, that can connect to only a REP socket (and other types associated with router/dealer patterns), so that's what your flowgraph would have to have. A REQ cannot connect to a REQ. And as your C++ is connecting, the block in the flowgraph would have to be binding (it's not clear in the question if that's what you've got).

Also, beware of REQ / REP's one out, one back behaviour. If you've sent something through the REQ socket, you can't send anything else through it until you've received and read the reply. And, if you've read a message (a "request") from the REP socket, you can't read anything else until you've sent something in reply. Things can get a little confused, if one program is restarted part way through (it's best to kill both, start afresh).

Also note that the end that "binds" is independent of the socket type; whilst it might feel natural that the REP socket should be the "server", and thus bind whilst the REQ socket is connected, you can in fact swap that round if you so wish.

@bazza All that you said makes sense. In GnuRadio I have a ZMQ REQ Message Source that is 'connected', so I changed it with a binding REP, but I'm still working on the serialization

Good luck with the serialisation. GNU Radio (re)invented its own serialisation, which is unfortunate because there are many extant standards they could have used instead and saved the work. They’re doing the same with their math library Volk, which is a pity because there’s standardised math libraries they could have targeted instead (eg VSIPL). I don’t know why, but many OSS projects give themselves a ton of extra work to do by constantly reinventing wheels. dBus also reinvented serialisation too, in a completely different way. It would have been simpler if they used the same one.

It’s up to projects to choose their own direction of course, but many projects struggle to attract volunteers and there is value in minimising the work to be done in maintaining a project. A founder may indeed have enthusiasm for creating their own library, but at the end of the day that’s code they have to persuade someone else to take on.

@bazza yes I noticed, it's giving me a very hard time. I can't find good serialize solutions. I'm trying to use pmt::serialize for C++ but unsuccessfully for now. Also I couldn't find serialize functions for zmq
